# TV show with a group of teens going into a video game with an AI assistant

Tags: story-identification, tv

I have been looking for days now determined to find this one TV show. It was on Netflix for a period of time. The show was recent, I believe it came out in 2018 but I'm not 100% on that. It was live action.

It was about a group of teens who get a weird home room class at their new school, they have to go into a virtual world to fight evil. There was an AI assistant who helped them, also if they died in the game they died in real life.

Comment: In which region do you live? Netflix has different shows for different regions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it possible you're looking for [*ReBoot: the Guardian Code*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ReBoot:_The_Guardian_Code)? It's a live-action reboot of classic animates series *ReBoot* which was broadcast on Netflix in 2018.

> Four teenaged gamers, who are members of an online game's highest-scoring team, meet in person on their first day at Alan Turing High School. Their enrollment was arranged by Vera, an artificial intelligence who has recruited the team as "Guardians" to physically enter and protect cyberspace. Early in the series, Vera is given a human body and locked out of cyberspace, so she enrolls as an exchange student. The Guardians battle the Sourcerer, a human hacker. Dark code is the Sourcerer's primary weapon against the world's computer systems. After his initial run-in with the Guardians, the Sourcerer reactivates the computer virus named Megabyte, the main antagonist of the original ReBoot, to help him from inside cyberspace.

They are assigned to "Room 0" as their homeroom, as seen in the trailer:

Comment: "A reboot of ReBoot" sounds weird. :)

Comment: @DavidW: It's really more of a sequel, but I couldn't resist.